# как сделать Cmake для vulkan

Tags: консоль, cmake, makefile, сборка, vulkan

Изучаю только make и Cmake...

В консоль ввожу:

> g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -o VulkanTest main.cpp -lglfw -lvulkan -ldl -lpthread -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi

Сделал makefile, занес в него, то что делал через консоль:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c++17 -O2
LDFLAGS = -lglfw -lvulkan -ldl -lpthread -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi

VulkanTest: main.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o VulkanTest main.cpp $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: test clean

test: VulkanTest
    ./VulkanTest

clean:
    rm -f VulkanTest
```

Все работает, так сказать компилируется.

Теперь хочу научиться использовать Cmake, но проблема пишет, что нет библиотек. Полный текст CMakeLists.txt, там есть комментарий, что пробовал несколько вариантов, но результат один, ошибка на библиотеки. Подскажите как должен быть написан CMakeLists.txt, что бы файл компилировался.
Код CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(VulkanTest)

# include_directories(/usr/include/)
# add_library(CVulkanTest  STATIC
# /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h
# /usr/include/glm/vec4.hpp
# /usr/include/glm/mat4x4.hpp
# )


#include_directories(include)
##find_library(GLFW_LIBRARY /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h)
#find_library(VEC4_LIBRARY /usr/include/glm/vec4.hpp)
#find_library(MAT4x4_LIBRARY /usr/include/glm/mat4x4.hpp)
# set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
# set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED on)
# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lglfw -lvulkan -ldl -lpthread -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi")
add_executable(VulkanTest main.cpp)
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(VulkanTest ${Vulkan_LIBRARY} ${Vulkan_GLSLC_EXECUTABLE})



target_compile_options(VulkanTest PUBLIC -std=c++17 -O2 -lglfw -lvulkan -ldl -lpthread -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi)


#target_link_libraries(VulkanTest ${GLFW_LIBRARY} ${VEC4_LIBRARY} ${MAT4x4_LIBRARY})
#target_compile_features(VulkanTest cxx_std_17)
```

Что выводит консоль:

```
cmake --build .
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable VulkanTest
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/main.cpp.o: в функции «main»:
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1a): неопределённая ссылка на «glfwInit»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x26): неопределённая ссылка на «glfwWindowHint»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x41): неопределённая ссылка на «glfwCreateWindow»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x81): неопределённая ссылка на «glfwPollEvents»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x89): неопределённая ссылка на «glfwWindowShouldClose»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x95): неопределённая ссылка на «glfwDestroyWindow»
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9a): неопределённая ссылка на «glfwTerminate»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/build.make:99: VulkanTest] Ошибка 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/all] Ошибка 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Ошибка 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Флаги, начинающиеся с `-l` - это флаги линковщика, строго говоря. Их нет смысла передавать в `target_compile_options`.

Чтобы починить конкретно эту проблему нужно добавить `glfw` в ваш вызов `target_link_libraries`, а по-хорошему - сперва использовать `find_package()`, чтобы его найти.

Comment: Проект собрался, стало выдавать в консоль "./VulkanTest: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/local/bin/glslc: cannot dynamically load position-independent executable" проверил библиотека на месте. Стёр "target_compile_options" добавил "find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)" и gflw в строку получилось так "target_link_libraries(VulkanTest ${Vulkan_LIBRARY} ${Vulkan_GLSLC_EXECUTABLE} glfw)". В чем может быть проблема, по сути проект, собрался так что это получаться другой вопрос задавать

Comment: `glslc` - это вообще программа, а не библиотека. Ее нельзя линковать.